# Combining change and keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

I have a form in which I am calculating cost for a product. It depends on both an input value they put in and a select they choose.

Is there a way to combine the `change` and `keyup` events into one cleaner segment?

My code is as followed:

https://jsfiddle.net/qrv57qtu/

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){
    var x = $('#input').val();
    var y = $('#select').val(); 
    if (y == '5') {
        var z = 5;
    }
    else if (y == '10') {
        var z = 10;
    }
    var z = x * y;
    $('#total').html(z);
});

$('#select').change(function(){
    var x = $(this).val();
    var y = $('#input').val();
    if (x == '5') {
        var z = 5;
    }
    else if (x == '10') {
        var z = 10;
    }
    var a = y * z;
    $('#total').html(a);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a single comma-delimited selector to get both elements. Then if you use the `on()` method you can provide a space-delimited string containing the event names you want to bind to, like this:

```
$('#input, #select').on('keyup change', function() {
    var x = $('#input').val();
    var y = $('#select').val();

    if (y == '5') {
        var z = 5;
    }
    else if (y == '10') {
        var z = 10;
    }

    var z = x * y;
    $('#total').html(z);
});
```

Also note that the `if` condition in your logic is entirely redundant as you overwrite the value of `z` at the end anyway

Comment: your missing the `#select`.

Comment: This is great - thank you! :) The if statement is necessary in my actual use because it sets a value from a string - was simplifying it a bit for this and did it a bit too hastily.

Comment: This will also raise the `keyup` event on `#select` and the `change` event on `#input`, which were not originally captured. Unlikely to make a difference in the long run, but a difference nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
 $(document).on("keyup change", "#input, #select", function(){
 var x = $('#select').val();
     var y = $('#input').val();

    if (x == '5') {
                var z = 5;
    }
    else if (x == '10') {
                var z = 10;
    }
    var a = y * z;
    $('#total').html(a);})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/itsrikin/gaL237qg/